# Is there a word which denotes expertise in framing search-engine queries?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a term which denotes that 'X person is an expert in framing search-engine queries' . Some synonyms such as slackers and hackers come to mind but they are pretty generic terms. Is there a specific term or should I just use 'slackers' or/and 'hackers' and be done with it.

Comment: Sorry - I just couldn't resist using my google-fu *specifically* to find a definition right here on ELU (it's not in "real" dictionaries yet, but [at least it's in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Google-fu)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers no - there is a difference. Google-fu as far as I know is having skills in google eccentricities as well, I was thinking/talking about all search engines, not just google in particular.

Comment: Good luck with persuading 5 high-rep users here about that, so they'll vote to reopen!

Comment: @shirish the definition provided (which seems as reputable as any) says *Skill in using search engines (especially Google) to quickly find useful information on the Internet* so it should be generic enough for requirements in question?